# Teams: How do I tell SO Teams we no longer use Slack?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

On the right side of our teams implementation is "Slack" in its own sub panel totally empty.

[image]

If I go to settings I cannot find a way to totally remove Slack. It tells me I am using an older version.  In reality we don't use Slack at all.

How do I get rid of Slack integration once and for all?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried step 1 in the instructions in that screenshot?

Comment: @TylerH - reread the question.  Those instructions are for updating slack.  We do not use slack.

Comment: Yes, so you should go to Slack and update it to remove the SO Teams integration, causing "Slack" to disappear from your SO Teams Integration section.

Comment: If you don't have Slack anymore, reinstall it and remove the integration, because you should have done that before uninstalling Slack. If you _never used Slack and never integrated it with SO Teams to begin with_, well that's a different matter (and a bug, not a support question), and the question here should be updated to reflect that info.

Comment: @TylerH Uninstalling the Stack Overflow app from your Slack instance does not inherently remove the application Id or "installation" of it from our side - only makes it stop functioning because it's no longer installed at the other end. The order of operations here doesn't really change anything.

Comment: @animuson So the _only_ way to do what JonH wants is to contact the support e-mail and request the integration be removed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have any team admin email us at teams-support@stackoverflow.com requesting the Slack integration be manually removed from the team. This effectively erases everything about your prior Slack integration and returns the settings page to a state as if it had never been installed. We do not currently offer any way to completely erase Slack traces within the admin settings UI.

Note, though, that this doesn't get rid of the Integrations box. It will change the "View notifications" link to be "Connect" instead and also start displaying the Microsoft Teams option, since neither one is installed.

Comment: Is there any chance to make this more self serving, reaching out to an email address is odd, also you might want to put that on a page for other teams out there - no one has any idea how that would work and I highly doubt all these people look on meta.

Comment: Sending an email to a support@company email address when you need their support on an application or service is actually quite a standard practice.

Comment: @TylerH - i would not want to use your apps then.  Something like this should be self serving, and if its not self serving well people are annoyed and have to break their process to remember to post on meta?  No where on that page does it say "Want to remove slack, sorry we don't allow you click here to contact support".

Comment: @JonH I agree if the only way to do this is to contact the company via e-mail, then it's not currently clear and should ideally also be something a customer could do themselves. But that's not what you said was odd. You simply said 'reaching out to an e-mail address is odd' for a support request, and... it's not. When you can't figure out how to do something in an app, contacting the app support line is _bog standard_ behavior.

Comment: @TylerH I think the main objection they have here is the theoretical possibility that the support team could deny the request. (In practice, there's no reason for them to do so here...)

Comment: @JonH Until very recently, you had to contact the team if you wanted your account on public Q&A deleted, so it's not like they're not making steps toward making things self-service.